# Scaling text in pictures

Tags: fonts, graphics, pstricks, scaling

I create pictures with pstricks, that contain rectangles and text within the rectangles. When I need to scale the picture, I use "psset unit=...", and all rectangles in my picture are scaled appropriately. However, the text does not change, and this ruins my entire picture. Either the text remains too small, or the text remains large and gets out of the rectangle.

Is there a way to scale a picture, such that the ratio between the text size and the graphics size will remain constant?

Comment: You can use \scalebox{h-scale}{v-scale}{your figure envir} from graphicx package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For text *and* graphic use:

```
\psscalebox{num1 num2}{stuff}
```

If you give two numbers in the first argument, num1 is used to scale
horizontally and num2 is used to scale vertically. If you give just one
number, the box is scaled by the same in both directions. You can’t
scale by zero, but negative numbers are OK, and have the effect of
flipping the box around the axis. You never know when you need to
do something like siht (`\psscalebox{-1 1}{this}`).

Comment: So with the default units (`xunit`, `yunit` and `unit`) at `1cm`, how can one automatically calculate `num1` if you change the units to (say) `unit=25pt`? Perhaps `\newdimen\oldpsunit\oldpsunit\psunit` in the preamble, and then calculate the ratio between `\oldpsunit` and `\psunit`?

Comment: `\def\numOne{\expandafter\strip@pt\dimexpr\psunit/28.45}`